# Python how to change colour of individual square of grid on mouse click

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, colors, python-imaging-library

How do I change the color of an individual square of the grid. This grid is drawn over an image. I calculated the center point of each square of the grid. When a user clicks on a specific square of the grid, I get the centroid of that square (already implemented). How can I change the color of the square of the grid. I have centroid of the clicked square in variable "closest_centroid".

```
# Get closes centroid
def closest_node(node, nodes):
    nodes = np.asarray(nodes)
    dist = np.sum((nodes - node)**2, axis=1)
    return np.argmin(dist)

# print co-ordinate function
def get_coords(event):

    mouse_xy = (event.x, event.y)
    closest_centroid = centers[closest_node(mouse_xy, centers)]
    print(closest_centroid)
```

My idea is to change the color of pixels of an image contained in the clicked square of the grid.

My libraries are:

```
import math
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
```

Comment: How are you producing the grid? What packages are you using to interact with the image? I see NumPy in the code but no mention of it or other libraries.

Comment: I updated the question by putting complete code

Comment: I'd prefer a happy medium but I'll take it I guess. What version of Python are you using or is this a library designed to be runnable on multiple versions?

Comment: Python2 version.

Comment: I spun my wheels for a bit trying to get Tkinter set up in Python2 before just doing it in Python3. Should be the same but let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already did the hard work so you just need a simple function like the following:

```
def change_color(center):
    step = step_size/2
    center_x, center_y = center
    canvas.create_rectangle(
       [
            center_x - step, 
            center_y - step, 
            center_x + step, 
            center_y + step
       ], 
       fill='red'
    )
```

Rather than printing the centroid, you'd just call this function at that point.

John showed in his full code (removed in an edit) that canvas was already setup to draw the grid. To setup canvas John did:

```
filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,height=img.size[0],width=img.size[0])
canvas.image = filename
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=filename)
canvas.pack()
```

Also he has step_size as:

```
step_size = int(img.width / step_count)
```

If the image isn't square, you'll need a `step_size_x` and a `step_size_y`

Comment: How to change the color from red to green, if user wants to change the color by mouse click on the same rectangle whose color is turned to red by click?

Comment: You'll need to keep a 2d list of how many times each cell has been clicked I think